# Почему не работает lParam pywin32

Tags: python, click, pywin32, координаты

По неизвестной мне причине, при использовании метода **win32gui.PostMessage()**, lParam игнорируется. Клик совершается, но не на тех координатах, что мне нужны.

```
def main(name="Minecraft 1.12.2"):
    # Окно
    window_name = name
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)

    lparam = win32api.MAKELONG(250, 250) # Корды клика
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Кликает по координатам
    win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lparam)
    win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lparam)
```

Дабы убедиться что проблема не в майнкрафте, протестировал в Crossout и paint.net, не сработало.

Взял код отсюда: https://qna.habr.com/q/961719 . В вопросе автор упоминает, что у него ВСЕ работает в одном приложении, значит и lParam у него работает корректно. Хэндл дочернего окна мне не нужен, т.к. майнкрафт - не блокнот, обычный клик и печатание работает и в мэин виндоу. Так почему у него работает, а у меня нет?

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import time


def click(x,y):
  hWnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None) # Получает хендл окна
  hwndChild = win32gui.GetWindow(hWnd, win32con.GW_CHILD) # Получает хендл дочернего окна
  lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y) # Задает координаты клика
  time.sleep(0.3)



  # Кликает по координатам
  win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
  win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)

  time.sleep(0.3)

  # Пишет нужную букву
  temp = win32api.SendMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_CHAR, 0x14, 0)
```

Comment: Стоит проверить, это координаты относительные (внутри окна) или абсолютные.

Comment: Только что протестировал с методом ScreenToClient(), что рассчитываюет координаты внутри окна, также 0 результата, координат нет

Comment: Наверно, дублировать вопрос не стоило. Но я там оставил в комментах вариант на попробовать. В конце концов, можно и разобраться с pywinauto, ведь там это реализовано для элемента в методе `click()`, и работает. Просто с текущей загрузкой не хватает времени самому проверить и выкатить рабочий код.